# Find all positions of an occurence in a char array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to write a method which takes in a single letter (string) and a char aray which creates a boolean array. The boolean array is then initialized with all positions as false. 
A for loop then iterates through the char array and for each position where the letter (guess) is found in the char array the same position in the boolean array is marked true.  The problem is in the if section of the for loop. The syntax is not what my JDE accepts.
Any tips gratefully received.

```
    boolean[] printIfTrue = new boolean[wordInArray.length];
    for (int i = 0 ; i == wordInArray.length ; i++) {
        if (wordInArray[i] == guess ){                   // problem
            printIfTrue[i] == true;                      // problem
        }

    }

    return printIfTrue;
}
```

Comment: What are types of `wordInArray` and `printIfTrue`? Anyway, `printIfTrue[i] == true;` should be with `=`, not `==`.

Comment: `guess` must be of type `char`; is it of type `string`?

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed, your loop termination condition should be `<` otherwise you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop could be rewritten as follows. Furthermore, `guess` should be of type `char`.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < wordInArray.length ; i++) {
    printIfTrue[i] = wordInArray[i] == guess;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, it took me some time to make up the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a String with a char. Your `guess` variable should be of type `char` (using `guess = valueEnteredByTheUserAsString.charAt(0)`).

`==` is a comparison operator. To assign a value to a variable, you must use `=`:

```
printIfTrue[i] = true;
```

I read `==` as *is same as*.:

```
if (wordInArray[i] == guess )
```

is read as

> if the ith char of wordInArray *is same as* guess

I read `=` as *becomes* or *takes the value of*:

```
printIfTrue[i] == true;
```

is read as

> the ith element of printIfTrue *becomes* true

Answer (score 0):

**== is Relational Operator**
 == Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if yes then condition becomes true.

```
(A == B) is not true.
```

**= is Assignment Operator**

=   Simple assignment operator, Assigns values from right side operands to left side operand

```
C = A + B will assign value of A + B into C
```

Don't mix them , and as said by @JB Nizet ,

you cannot directly compare String with Character , I am assuming **wordsInArray** is your Array of Characters and **guess** is the String, So you can use

```
wordsInArray[i]==guess.charAt(i);
printIfTrue[i] = true;
```